# SQL запрос по группировке сессий пользователя

Tags: mysql, sql

Помогите сделать SQL запрос по заданным условиям:

Таблица содержит информацию о пользовательских сессиях. Написать запрос, который вернет максимальное число одновременных подключений для каждого пользователя и минимальное время, когда это произошло.

t.username – логин пользователя ;
t.logon_time – время старта сессии
logoff_time – время закрытия сессии

Comment: такой запрос прожорливый будет и сложный. как я вижу задачу (возможно неправ): надо вывести топ юзеров спамеров. тогда просто сортируем по общей сумме времени сессий для юзера + количество этих сессий. у спамера будет минимум времени на сайте при максимуме сессий.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT username, logon_time event_time, 1 weight FROM source_table
          UNION ALL
          SELECT username, logoff_time, -1 FROM source_table ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT username, 
                 event_time, 
                 SUM(weight) OVER (PARTITION BY username ORDER BY event_time, weight) amount
          FROM cte1 ),
cte3 AS ( SELECT username, 
                 event_time, 
                 amount,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY username ORDER BY amount DESC, event_time ASC) rn 
          FROM cte2 )
SELECT username, event_time, amount
FROM cte3
WHERE rn = 1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=67e7466de887c8a9ea85601c4e9d7958)